# How many public key can a .cert/PEM file have?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Provided I have a valid CA issued .cert file. Technically, how many keys a single .cert file can have? more than one public key? or only one public key

Comment: There are many kinds of certificates, but an _X.509 publickey certificate_ -- the only kind commonly used on the web and apparently the type you want -- contains exactly one publickey, belonging to the subject. It is also signed _by_ a keypair belonging to the issuer; that 'signing' (more exactly, verifying) publickey is identified by, but is not in, the certificate. A _file_ can contain one certificate or many, and each certificate can be for a different subject and contain a different publickey.

Comment: For same subject, will CA issue more than one certificates? for key rotation. I believe it is technically possible but still would like to hear out experts option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, an X.509 certificate (RFC5280) contains exactly one public key. No more, no less.

> For same subject, will CA issue more than one certificates?

CA may issue as many certificates to same entity as necessary. There are no limitations on the amount of issued certificates per subject.